# Loop over Specified Events in Data Table in R

Tags: r, loops, data.table

I need to calculate the number of occurrences of specific events over specified time periods. Assume I have the following data:

```
set.seed(1453)
id = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2)
x_1 = sample(0:1, 10, TRUE)
x_5 = sample(0:1, 10, TRUE)
date = c('2016-01-01', 
    '2016-02-01',
    '2016-02-23',
    '2016-03-04',
    '2016-04-01',
    '2016-01-01', 
    '2016-02-01',
    '2016-02-23',
    '2016-03-04',
    '2016-04-01'

)

df = data.frame(id,date=as.Date(date),snapshot_date = as.Date(date)+1,x_1,x_5)

df$x_1_n <- ifelse((df$x_1 ==1), TRUE, FALSE)
df$x_5_n <- ifelse(df$x_5==1, TRUE, FALSE)
```

So my data look like this:

```
 > df
    id  date      snapshot_date x_1 x_5 x_1_n x_5_n
1   1 2016-01-01    2016-01-02    1   0  TRUE FALSE
2   1 2016-02-01    2016-02-02    0   1  FALSE  TRUE
3   1 2016-02-23    2016-02-24    1   1  TRUE  TRUE
4   1 2016-03-04    2016-03-05    0   0  FALSE FALSE
5   1 2016-04-01    2016-04-02    0   1  FALSE  TRUE
6   2 2016-01-01    2016-01-02    1   1  TRUE  TRUE
7   2 2016-02-01    2016-02-02    1   0  TRUE FALSE
8   2 2016-02-23    2016-02-24    0   0 FALSE FALSE
9   2 2016-03-04    2016-03-05    0   0 FALSE FALSE
10  2 2016-04-01    2016-04-02    1   1  TRUE  TRUE
```

Now I create dates varaibles going back 3 months.

```
library(lubridate)
for (i in 1:3) {

DATE_MO <- as.Date(df$snapshot_date) %m-% months(i)
df[,paste0("DATE_MO", i)] <- DATE_MO
}
```

I have variables x_1, x_5. I need to write a loop that goes through all of those variables x_1,x_5 and calculate the number of occurrences between certain dates. The original code runs and is correct. But I want to see how to simplify it using the for loop so that I don't have to manually copy-paste the code for each x_1 and x_5 as the number of x_'s and dates are bigger in the original version.

```
library(data.table)
df <- data.table(df)

df[,c("x1_dminus_mo1",
         "x1_dminus_mo2",
         "x1_dminus_mo3"


) :=. (df[x_1_n][df[,.(id,DATE_MO1,snapshot_date)], on=.
                  (id, date >= DATE_MO1, date < snapshot_date), .N, by = .EACHI] $N
   ,

   df[x_1_n][df[,.(id,DATE_MO2, DATE_MO1)], on=.
                  (id, date >= DATE_MO2, date < DATE_MO1), .N, by = .EACHI] $N

   ,

   df[x_1_n][df[,.(id,DATE_MO3, DATE_MO2)], on=.
                  (id, date >= DATE_MO3, date < DATE_MO2), .N, by = .EACHI] $N
)]

df[,c("x5_dminus_mo1",
  "x5_dminus_mo2",
  "x5_dminus_mo3"


) :=. (df[x_5_n][df[,.(id,DATE_MO1,snapshot_date)], on=.
             (id, date >= DATE_MO1, date < snapshot_date), .N, by = .EACHI] $N
   ,

   df[x_5_n][df[,.(id,DATE_MO2, DATE_MO1)], on=.
             (id, date >= DATE_MO2, date < DATE_MO1), .N, by = .EACHI] $N

   ,

   df[x_5_n][df[,.(id,DATE_MO3, DATE_MO2)], on=.
             (id, date >= DATE_MO3, date < DATE_MO2), .N, by = .EACHI] $N
 )]
```